# Does a non-fraction number have a reciprocal?

Tags: fractions

As far as I understand from [this Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fraction#Proper_and_improper_fractions), $\frac 73$ is a reciprocal of $\frac 37$;

But can a term "reciprocal" be applied to a non-fraction number?

For example, it would be correct to say:

> reciprocal of $\frac 21$ is $\frac 12$

But would it also be correct to say:

> reciprocal of 2 is $\frac 12$

?

Comment: Absolutely not.

Comment: @SenZen Can you, please, cite some sources because supporter *jjagmath* gave me the opposite answer below and now I am confused.

Comment: @brilliant literally like two paragraphs beyond what you cite, they say nonzero integers are expressed as fractions over 1 and have reciprocals .

Comment: @rschwieb - You are citing the same source (my source) below two opposite answers. One is this one, and the other one is that of the supporter named *jjagmath* (below). So, which one of the two answers do you consider as correct?

Comment: @rschwieb - "beyond what you cite, they say nonzero integers are expressed as fractions over 1 and have reciprocals" - That's exactly when they are expressed as fractions. But what about the cases when they are not expressed as fractions? That's, in fact, what my question was about.

Comment: @brilliant my comment is not related to SenZen’s in any way other than being next to it.  I do not agree with senzens comment. I agree with jjagmath’s answer. And even if neither of those things were here now, the article you cited has a complete explanation right next to what you cited. It does not say that there are “cases where integers are written as fractions” it says you can always write them as fractions. I think you are talking about a distinction that doesn’t exist.

Comment: @rschwieb - I see. Don't be so rude next time.

Comment: @brilliant Sorry, I realize it is unpleasant to be called out on something like this.  I could have been gentler.  Good luck with your studies.

Comment: How are you defining reciprocal? That’s where you should start.

Comment: @brilliant You rely on authority too much

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, every number have a reciprocal, except $0$. It's also called its multiplicative inverse.

Comment: Can you, please, cite some sources because @SenZen gave me the opposite answer and now I am confused.

Comment: @brilliant source: the wiki article you cited but didn’t read completely.

Comment: @rschwieb - You are citing the same source (my source) below two opposite answers. One is this one, and the other one is that of the supporter named *SenZen* (above). So, which one of the two answers do you consider as correct?

Answer (score 1):

Yes.  For instance, $\dfrac1{\pi}$ is the reciprocal of $\pi$.  $\dfrac1r$ is the reciprocal of $r$ for any nonzero $r\in \Bbb R$.